# Vertically align <span> in <li> with unknown height

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists, center

I am working on some kind of context menu. The arrow that indicates whether a row will provide a submenu should always be centered. This works well with single line `<li>` elements, but not with multiline. Here the `<span>` that contains the arrow symbol is aligned with the last line of the text.

It gets worse if the menu contains a scrollbar, then the arrow is beneath the line.

I am thankful for any help, the solution can contain JS/jQuery if that's required to be flexible.

You can find my current source here: http://jsfiddle.net/ass9sxo6/3/

Btw: Would be even better if the arrow symbol was in the padding area of the `<li>` so that it doesn't steal any space that could be used for text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `<span class="indicator"></span>` to the end of every `<li>` element you can use CSS3 `:after` selector with the `content` attribute to append an arrow at the end of every `<li>` element.

Then you set CSS attribute `position:relative` on each `<li>` element so that it's child elements will inherit its position. And on each `li:after` content you can set `display:block` and `position:absolute` along with `top:50%` and `margin-top:-0.5em` to get the vertical alignment you want.

Here's a modification to your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ass9sxo6/6/

And the CSS attributes I added to demonstrate the effect:

```
li {position:relative;}
li:after {
    content: '›';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

P.S. You should try use Ascii symbols where possible rather than base64 images to keep the file size small and the code easy to understand.

Comment: I really like that solution, totally shrinked my CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

You could center your span with this addition in your css:

```
.box li { 
  position: relative;
}

.box ul li span { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ass9sxo6/4/

**Positioned** the `span` element absolute with top / bottom / right values 0 and set **margin** to auto. In order to work needs relative **position** to container element `li`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `absolute`:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ass9sxo6/7/).

Answer (score 1):

Set `.indicator` element to `position: absolute;` (and give its' parent `<li>` non-static positioning). Give it custom right offset (say: `right: 5px;`), set `.top` and `.bottom` to 0, and set `.line-height` to parent `<li>`s' height. It centers an indicator verticaly automatically as `<li>`s' height changes. Something like this should work fine:

```
.indicator {
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  bottom      : 0;
  display     : block;
  line-height : 50px; /* same as parents' height, assuming its' 50px... */
  position    : absolute;
  right       : 5px;
  top         : 0;
}
```

---

I sometimes use this `less` snippet to easily tweak menu properties. Adjust the variables in file header, export it as css, run: `lessc --clean-css ul-stacked.less > ul-stacked.min.css`, and slap a `ul-stacked` class to any `<ul>` with this structure: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ass9sxo6/8/)

```
<ul class="ul-stacked">
  <li><span>ipsum</span></li>
  <li class="parent"> <span> nulla <span class="indicator">&gt;</span> </span> </li>
  <li><span>lorem</span></li>
  <!-- etc. -->
</ul>
```

```
// ul-stacked.less

// #vars

@class-name          : ul-stacked;
@class-name-feedback : indicator;
@class-name-parent   : parent;

@body-bg               : #f8f8f8;
@body-frame-bg         : #ccc;
@body-frame-width      : 2px;
@body-height-base      : 50px;
@body-pad-content-base : .2em;
@border-radius-base    : 2px;
@feedback-offs-right   : 1em;
@spacing-bottom-base   : 2px;


@body-bg-hover         : lighten(@body-bg, 2%);
@body-height           : @body-height-base * 1;
@spacing-bottom        : @spacing-bottom-base + @body-frame-width / 2;


// #mixins

.reset-base() {
  border  : none;
  margin  : 0;
  outline : none;
  padding : 0;
}

.wrapper-fluid() {
  display : block;
  height  : auto;
  width   : 100%;
}

.list-unstyled() {
  list-style          : none;
  list-style-position : outside;
  margin              : 0;
  padding             : 0;
}

.borders(@r: @border-radius-base) {
  border-radius: @r;
}

ul.@{class-name} {

  .list-unstyled;
  .reset-base;
  .wrapper-fluid;

    > li {

      .borders;
      .reset-base;

      background : @body-frame-bg;
      display    : block;
      float      : none;
      height     : @body-height;
      position   : relative;
      width      : 100%;

      > * {

        &:hover {
          background : @body-bg-hover;
        }

        background : @body-bg;
        bottom     : @body-frame-width;
        display    : block;
        left       : @body-frame-width;
        padding    : @body-pad-content-base;
        position   : absolute;
        right      : @body-frame-width;
        top        : @body-frame-width;
      }
    }

    > li {
      margin-bottom: @spacing-bottom;
    }

    > li:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    > li.@{class-name-parent} {
      > * {
        > .@{class-name-feedback} {
          .reset-base;
          bottom      : 0;
          display     : block;
          line-height : @body-height;
          position    : absolute;
          right       : @feedback-offs-right;
          top         : 0;
        }
      }
    }
}

// eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `span` tag and make the background image to `li` tag... Its very simple.

Check this [**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/ass9sxo6/5/).

```css
.box li {
  background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-right-b-16.png);
  background-position:right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>
            This will be some multiline content
        </li>
        <li>
            and single line
        </li>
        <li>
            This will be some multiline content
        </li>
        <li>
            and single line
        </li>
        <li>
            This will be some multiline content
        </li>
        <li>
            and single line
        </li>
    </ul>
<div>
```